# generating iWork Numbers file on iOS

Tags: ios, iwork, apple-numbers

Has anyone had any luck with generating a spreadsheet file in iWork Numbers format on iOS? At least is there any documentation on the file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a publicly documented file format. It can open CSV and some Excel file formats, [as listed here on Apple's Knowledge Base](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4067).